# 70’s - 80’s Cartoon. Robots? Scooby Doo maybe?

Tags: story-identification

There was this cartoon episode.  Something like Scooby Doo.  This episode involved a villain that used old/ rusty animatronic type robots.  I distinctly remember a pirate and a cowboy robot.  These robots were kind of torn up and had exposed wires and mechanics.  The pirate had a bandana and at one point was on some sort of raft with the cowboy after capturing the good guys... I think.

Way obscure stuff.  Any help?